# Retornar valor quando $.getJSON terminar

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho um diretório com subdiretórios, e o código verifica se esses subdiretórios são validos consultando o `settings.json` deles, caso tenha (que é obrigatório para ser válido), porém o `$.getJSON` não funciona retornando o conteúdo do arquivo, e sim passando-o como argumento para uma função, porém eu preciso que a função `getThemes` retorne a lista de subdiretórios validos quando todos os `$.getJSON` estiverem prontos, código:

```
getDirectories = (srcpath) => {
    return fs.readdirSync(srcpath).filter(function(file)
    {
        return !['.', '..'].includes(file) && fs.statSync(path.join(srcpath, file)).isDirectory();
    });
}

getThemes = () => {
    let directories = getDirectories(path.join(process.cwd(), 'themes'));
    let out = [];

    for (let dir of directories)
        $.getJSON(path.join('themes', dir, 'settings.json')).done((json) => {
            if (json.version && json.name)
                out.push(json)
        })

    return out
}
```

Comment: O que é essa variável `a` no seu código? Está certo isto? Não deveria ser `json` ou algo do gênero nesse `push`?

Comment: @GabrielKatakura sim, esqueci de alterar, o correto era `json`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$.getJSON` retorna uma `Promise`, logo o funcionamento do `out.push` é feito de forma assíncrona, por isso que está retornando `out` vazio. Para resolver isso, você terá que retornar uma `Promise` em `getThemes`.

```
getThemes = () => {
    let directories = getDirectories(path.join(process.cwd(), 'themes'));
    let directoriesAsPromise = directories.map(dir => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            $.getJSON(path.join('themes', dir, 'settings.json')).then(resolve, reject);
        });
    }); 

    return Promise.all(directoriesAsPromise).then(results => {
        return results.filter(json => json.version && json.name);
    });
};
```

Para usar, basta você usar como uma `Promise` normalmente, sendo que o retorno em `then` será os diretórios filtrados.

```
getThemes().then(directories => console.log(directories));
```